Uniform convergence of sequence of continuous functions implies uniform continuity?
I recently encountered a question where I'm not sure if I answered it correctly, given that I didn't use one of the assumptions. So here's the question:
Prove that if a sequence of continuous functions ${\{f_n:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\}}$ is uniformly convergent, then:
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\space\exists\delta>0,\space\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N},\space\forall{x,y}\in[0,1],\space|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|{f_n}(x)-{f_n}(y)|<\epsilon.$$
My attempt was as follows:
Since $[0,1]$ is a compact set, and continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous, each ${f_n}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. Then by definition:
$$\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N},\space\forall\epsilon>0,\space\exists{\delta_n}>0,\space\forall{x,y}\in[0,1],\space|x-y|<{\delta_n}\Rightarrow|{f_n}(x)-{f_n}(y)|<\epsilon.$$
Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta=\min({\delta_1},\space{\delta_2},\space{\delta_3},...)$. Then, $\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}$, $\space\forall{x,y}\in[0,1]$, we have that $\space|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|{f_n}(x)-{f_n}(y)|<\epsilon$, which concludes the proof.
As you have seen, the proof does not require any assumption of the sequence being uniformly convergent. Please enlighten me on where I may have made a mistake in the proof. Thank you!

$\min({\delta_1},\space{\delta_2},\space{\delta_3},...)$ may not exist, as there is a countably infinite number of $\delta_i$'s.
